# ZF2 pagination is not working in linux server?

Tags: linux, windows, pagination, zend-framework2

In my windows server pagination working fine but when I put up it in linux server it show this error `Fatal error: Cannot access private property Zend\Paginator\SerializableLimitIterator::$count in /var/www/foldername/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Db/ResultSet/AbstractResultSet.php on line 243`

I don't really know what is the real problem. I guess nothing.

Comment: you probably have a lesser error level on windows which is allowing this to run with the error

Comment: Looks like , the way you are calling is wrong , can you post the action where you or calling it , because I have tried using the same class it worked for me with out any trouble